# go: how to convert string to hash.Hash64

Tags: go, interface

I try to use https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/steakknife/bloomfilter but its `Add()` method requires a hash.Hash64,  how can I convert a string (or []byte) to hash.Hash64?

Comment: see https://pkg.go.dev/hash#example-package-BinaryMarshaler

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is this:

```
myString := "hello world"
myHash := fnv.New64()
myHash.Write([]byte(myString))
```